# Clearing the Console

Tags: c#

I am using `Console.Clear()` command to wipe everything in my console.  In my program the last two lines are:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your answer is:" + answer);                   
Console.Clear();
```

the problem is that everything in the function works but the statement "Your answer is ..." doesn't show up.  I guess `Console.Clear()` clears it also and that's my problem.  I want it to be shown.

Comment: Move `Console.Clear` up. Or use `Console.ReadKey();` after `Console.WriteLine` and once the user press any key then clear your console.

Answer (score 5):

Reverse the order:

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Your answer is:" + answer);
```

This clears the screen and *then* displays the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer *is* being displayed, but it's cleared before you can see it.

You could add a `Console.Read()` or a `Console.ReadLine()` between the two statements.

Comment: `--1` why would he need a Thread.Sleep.. all he needs is a Console.Read() to suspend the console after the Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Console.WriteLine("Your answer is:" + answer);   
Console.ReadKey();                
Console.Clear();
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("Your answer is:" + answer);   
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);//wait 2 sec    
Console.Clear();
```